# Cypress - re-run config from plugin file middle of tests

Tags: node.js, cypress

I have a question, I have a need to re-run config in middle of tests because role that we use has only an hour of permission. You can't even extend role permission as we do role chaining while using this role. Has anyone come across this issue? My question is how to re-run code in `cypress/plugins/index.js` to get a fresh credentials when test fails or if test runs after credentials are expired?

Plugin/index.ts

```
import * as secretsManager from '@amzn/cypress-midway-plugin/secret_manager';
import PluginEvents = Cypress.PluginEvents;
import PluginConfigOptions = Cypress.PluginConfigOptions;
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'

import { CYPRESS_PRINCIPAL, CYPRESS_SECRET_ID, REGION, STAGE } from '../resources/constants';
import fetchSigv4Session from "./sigv4";
import getEnvVariables from "./env-variables";

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */

export default async (on: PluginEvents, config: PluginConfigOptions): Promise<PluginConfigOptions> => {  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
  // assuming running from Hydra

  on('task', {
    log (message) {
      console.log(message)
      return null
    }
  })

  config.env.SIGV4_SESSION = await fetchSigv4Session(AWS);

  config.env.REGION = REGION;
  config.env.CYPRESS_ENV_VARIABLES = getEnvVariables(STAGE)

  on('after:run', () => {
    console.log("Test finished at: ", new Date())
  });

  return config;
};
```

Support/index.ts

```
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import AWS = require('aws-sdk');
import fetchSigv4Session from '../plugins/sigv4';
import './commands'

// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')


const CYPRESS_LOG_NAME = 'Login with Midway';

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  console.warn('Uncaught exception (suppressed):', err);
  return false;
});

//Runs at start of each test suites
before(() => {
  
    cy.log("Starting Authentication")
    cy.setCookie('region', Cypress.env('REGION'));
    cy.setCookie('session', Cypress.env('SIGV4_SESSION'));
    

    const preserve = [
      'session',
      'cypress',
      'region'
    ];
    Cypress.Cookies.defaults({ preserve });

    return cy.request({
      url: `https://authentication.api.com/api/session-status`,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {'Clear-Site-Data': "*"} //This will allow us to do a fresh call rather than using browser's cache
    }, ).then(async response => {
      Cypress.log({
        name: CYPRESS_LOG_NAME, message: [`Logged in and running cypress tests.`]
      });
      cy.wrap(response, {log: false});
    })
});
```

So, when ever I hit this issue, I need to get a fresh credentials, if I do in between test or in cypress fail event handler, it doesn't recognize any node environment variable. Not sure if there is any other hook I can call to have environment to run code in `plugins/index.ts` run properly

Comment: I can give you a better answer - can you post the code please, for a concrete example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To re-run the configuration in `plugins` mid-test, you might create a task for the steps that currently only run at startup.

This is approximate pattern only, as I don't know the full application.

```js
...
function runConfig() {
  config.env.SIGV4_SESSION = await fetchSigv4Session(AWS);
  config.env.REGION = REGION;
  config.env.CYPRESS_ENV_VARIABLES = getEnvVariables(STAGE)
}

export default async (on: PluginEvents, config: PluginConfigOptions): Promise<PluginConfigOptions> => {  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits

  on('task', {
    ...
    runConfig () {
      runConfig()    // for mid-test change
      return null
    }
  })

  // for startup
  runConfig()

  return config;
}
```

Similarly, in Support (if needed), this is the general pattern:

```js
...

Cypress.Command.add('runConfig', () => {
    cy.log("Starting Authentication")
    cy.setCookie('region', Cypress.env('REGION'));
    cy.setCookie('session', Cypress.env('SIGV4_SESSION'));
    

    const preserve = [
      'session',
      'cypress',
      'region'
    ];
    Cypress.Cookies.defaults({ preserve });

    return cy.request({
      url: `https://authentication.api.com/api/session-status`,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {'Clear-Site-Data': "*"} //This will allow us to do a fresh call rather than using browser's cache
    }, ).then(async response => {
      Cypress.log({
        name: CYPRESS_LOG_NAME, message: [`Logged in and running cypress tests.`]
      });
      cy.wrap(response, {log: false});
    })
})

//Runs at start of each test suites
before(() => {
  runConfig()
});
```

You now have the ability to call both of those in any test or hook

```js
it('runs new config', () => {
  ...
  cy.task('runConfig')
  
  ...
  cy.runConfig()
})
```

Answer (score 6):

The way to change configuration inside a test is to use `Cypress.config(configKey, newConfigValue)`.

But Cypress has fixed keys for config, so for credentials you are probably using environment variable which is a similar syntax: `Cypress.env(envKey, newEnvValue)`.

This can be used for any key, not just ones defined by Cypress.

The proper way to manage credentials is using the `cy.session()` command. For example,

```js
// Caching session when logging in via API
cy.session(username, () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/login',
    body: { username, password },
  }).then(({ body }) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('authToken', body.token)
  })
})
```

Then you can change credentials by calling the `cy.session()` with a different `username`.

Here is the reference for further reading: [Session](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session)